Convert one object to two different DTOs based on a condition
In one of our projects we are using .NET AutoMapper (version 10.1.1). In others, we realized using AutoMapper is too complex and moved to direct manually mapping which is way faster and way more flexible (I prefer this approach myself too).
Anyway we have next backend model TextDocumentItem, which has next property:
public bool RichTextFormatting { get; set; }

Depending on whether the RichTextFormatting property is true, we want to map this to RichTextBoxObjectApi and vice-versa to TextBoxObjectApi.
this.CreateMap<TextDocumentItem, TextBoxObjectApi>();
this.CreateMap<TextDocumentItem, RichTextBoxObjectApi>();

Does AutoMapper support something like this? I was looking for the .If method.
In pseudo-code:
this.CreateMap<TextDocumentItem, TextBoxObjectApi>()
    .If(src => src.RichTextFormatting == true);

this.CreateMap<TextDocumentItem, RichTextBoxObjectApi>();
    .If(src => src.RichTextFormatting == false);


AFAIK, CreateMap<TSrc, TDest>() aims to define the mapping rule for the source to destination. You must provide the type to be mapped (_mapper.Map<TDest>(source)) during mapping. So your idea on defining which Destination class to be mapped should be implemented in the method with your logic (check condition and map by type), not rely on the AutoMapper.

Dem based on my previous comment.

@YongShun this qualifies for a valid answer.

You must provide the destination type when performing the mapping in AutoMapper. Hence, you should implement your logic that determines which type to be mapped, instead of relying on AutoMapper (AFAIK, there is no such feature).
You may look to define a (common) interface for both TextBoxObjectApi and RichTextBoxObjectApi classes if you are attempting to perform further logic based on its type.
public ITextBoxObjectApi MapTextDocumentItem(IMapper _mapper, TextDocumentItem source)
{
    if (source.RichTextFormatting)
        return _mapper.Map<RichTextBoxObjectApi>(source);
    else
        return _mapper.Map<TextBoxObjectApi>(source);
}

public interface ITextBoxObjectApi
{

}

public class TextBoxObjectApi : ITextBoxObjectApi
{

}

public class RichTextBoxObjectApi : ITextBoxObjectApi
{

}

Caller:
var mappedItem = MapTextDocumentItem(_mapper, /* TextDocumentItem instance */);

if (mappedItem is TextBoxObjectApi)
{
    // Implementation for TextBoxObjectApi instance
}
else if (mappedItem is RichTextBoxObjectApi)
{
    // Implementation for RichTextBoxObjectApi instance
}

Demo @ .NET Fiddle
